# Подсчет баланса пользователей в хранимой процедуре PostreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

Нужна помощь в написании SQL запроса, DB-PostgreSQL.
Есть таблица "txs" где хранятся данные о транзакциях по счетам клиентов:

Таблица "txs":

```
user_from_id | user_to_id | amount | status
   1               2         35      'wait'
   1             null        5       'success'
  null             1         40      'pending'
   2              null       10      'failed'
```

Мне необходимо  используя данные из таблицы "txs" сделать подсчет баланса по каждому пользователю. 
Если status 'wait' или 'pending' -  то сумму считаем в pending_in или pending_out  (для wallet_from_id - суммируем amount в колонку pending_out,  для wallet_to_id - суммируем amount в колонку pending_in).
Если status 'success' -  то считаем в колонку balance  ( для wallet_from_id   вычитаем amount из balance,  для wallet_to_id - суммируем amount к balance).
 Транзакции со статусом 'failed' не учитываем.

На выходе должна получиться такая таблица:

```
user_id | balance | pending_in | pending_out
1           -5         40            35
2            0         35             0
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с написанием скрипта. Не получается в результирующей таблице получить объединенные колонки `user_from_id` и `user_to_id` с правильным подсчетом балансов
Вот моя песочница с данными  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/33d53d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ на данную задачу  : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a9654100f200af352f4be886ec52075c

```
CREATE TABLE txs (
user_from_id int,
user_to_id int,
amount numeric NOT NULL,
status text NOT NULL CHECK (status IN ('wait', 'success', 'pending', 'failed'))
);

INSERT INTO txs (user_from_id, user_to_id, amount, status)
VALUES 
(1, 2, 35, 'wait'),
(1, NULL, 5, 'success'),
(NULL, 1, 40, 'pending'),
(2, NULL, 10, 'failed');
```

Собственно запрос:

```
WITH calc_base AS (
-- From
SELECT t.user_from_id AS user_id, -t.amount AS amount, t.status
  FROM txs AS t
 WHERE status <> 'failed' AND t.user_from_id IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
-- To
SELECT t.user_to_id, t.amount, t.status
  FROM txs AS t
 WHERE status <> 'failed' AND t.user_to_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT user_id, 
       COALESCE(SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE status = 'success'), 0) AS balance,
       COALESCE(SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE amount > 0 AND status IN ('wait', 'pending')), 0) AS pending_in,
       -COALESCE(SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE amount < 0 AND status IN ('wait', 'pending')), 0) AS pending_out
  FROM calc_base
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY user_id;
```

Comment: День добрый. Приведите решение прям в ответе лучше.